# Login for phpmyadmin failing, can't set up username and password

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

For my website, https://maxstechandmathsite.azurewebsites.net, I've already installed phpmyadmin by cloning the repository of files from the downloaded .zip folder. Problem is, I can't log in to the MySQL server after trying to set up the credentials on the `config.inc.php` file which was renamed from `config.inc.sample.php`. Here's what the file looks like:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '23.100.82.11';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'MY_PASSWORD';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'Max\'s Tech and Math Site';
```

I've tried setting the `AllowNoPassword` to true, but it still doesn't work. I also switched the `host` from `localhost` to the IP address I found for my server when doing an `nslookup` command - perhaps that is what's wrong? Am I missing some type of reference for MySQL server?

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: There is a very simple error message saying "cannot login to MySQL Server", but another one saying "mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond." The second one might suggest some type of timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel rather dumb for my question. The thing is, I didn't set up any MySQL server instance for my connection. I figured my host provider would provide a MySQL server at port 3306, but they didn't; you can't just assume that. So, I set up a MySQL server instance using free hosting at https://www.freemysqlhosting.net. I copied the server name, database name, username, and password into the `config.inc.php` file, and now I can log in.